# Link: Unresolved Externals (stemmed from Polymorphism)

Tags: visual-c++, inheritance, com, polymorphism, unresolved-external

I've been spending the past two days on this, and Googling as much as I can to figure this error out. Unfortunately, everything I've found so far hasn't seemed to resolve a solution. I've *triple checked* my include guards, along with my virtual functions for definitions (which they all have), and have commented out various code blocks which I thought might be a contributor to the issue. Alas, nothing I've tried has helped. Same error.

If someone could take a look at my code and point me in the right direction, it would be a huge help.

The error is as follows:

```
1>TriangleDemo.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual bool __thiscall stitch::PixelShader::CreateShader(void)" (?CreateShader@PixelShader@stitch@@UAE_NXZ)
1>FileUtility.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual bool __thiscall stitch::PixelShader::CreateShader(void)" (?CreateShader@PixelShader@stitch@@UAE_NXZ)
1>TriangleDemo.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall stitch::PixelShader::Recompile(void)" (?Recompile@PixelShader@stitch@@UAEXXZ)
1>FileUtility.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall stitch::PixelShader::Recompile(void)" (?Recompile@PixelShader@stitch@@UAEXXZ)
1>FileUtility.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall stitch::PixelShader::PixelShader(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class std::tr1::shared_ptr<struct RenderData> const &)" (??0PixelShader@stitch@@QAE@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@000ABV?$shared_ptr@URenderData@@@tr1@3@@Z) referenced in function "public: static class stitch::PixelShader __cdecl stitch::FileUtility::LoadPixelShader(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class std::tr1::shared_ptr<struct RenderData> const &)" (?LoadPixelShader@FileUtility@stitch@@SA?AVPixelShader@2@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@00ABV?$shared_ptr@URenderData@@@tr1@5@@Z)
1>C:\Programming\C++\GraphicsWin32\D3DTechDemo\Debug\D3DTechDemo.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
```

**Code - Headers**

**//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

---*Shader.hpp*---

```
class Shader {
    public:
        enum ShaderType { ShaderTypePixel, ShaderTypeVertex, ShaderTypeHull };
    public:
        Shader( const std::string& filename, const std::string& shaderSrc, const std::string& entrypointFuncName,
                const std::string& shaderProfile, const RenderData_sptr& renderData_ptr,
                ShaderType sType );

        virtual ~Shader( void )
        {
            mCompiledShader->Release();
            delete mCompiledShader;
            mCompiledShader = NULL;
        }

        virtual bool CreateShader( void );
        virtual void Recompile( void );

    public:
        const std::string& Filename;
        const std::string& ShaderSrc;
        const std::string& EntrypointFuncName;
        const std::string& ShaderProfile;
        const ShaderType ShdrType;

    public:
        inline D3DDataBlob*& GetCompiledShader_mutableRef( void ) 
        { return mCompiledShader; }

        inline const D3DDataBlob* const GetCompiledShader_const( void ) const  
        { return mCompiledShader; }

        inline HRESULT GetCompilerResultMessage( void ) const
        { return mCompilerResultMessage; }

        inline const bool IsCompiled( void ) const
        { return mIsCompiled; }

    protected:
        HRESULT         mCompilerResultMessage;
        D3DDataBlob*    mCompiledShader;
        RenderData_sptr mRenderData;
        bool            mIsCompiled;
    };
```

**//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

--*PixelShader.hpp*--

```
class PixelShader : public Shader 
    {
    public:
        PixelShader( const std::string& filename, const std::string& shaderSrc, const std::string& entrypointFuncName,
                     const std::string& shaderProfile, const RenderData_sptr& renderData_ptr );

        virtual ~PixelShader()
        {   
            mPixelShader_ptr->Release();
            delete mPixelShader_ptr;
            mPixelShader_ptr = NULL;
        }

        bool CreateShader( void );

        void Recompile( void );

    public:
        inline D3DPixelShader* GetPixelShader_ptr( void ) const
        { return mPixelShader_ptr; }

    private:
        D3DPixelShader* mPixelShader_ptr;
    };
```

**//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

--*VertexShader.hpp*--

```
class VertexShader : public Shader 
    {
    public:
        VertexShader( const std::string& filename, const std::string& shaderSrc, const std::string& entrypointFuncName,
                      const std::string& shaderProfile, const RenderData_sptr& renderData_ptr );

        virtual ~VertexShader( void )
        {
            mVertexShader_ptr->Release();
            delete mVertexShader_ptr;
            mVertexShader_ptr = NULL;
        }

        virtual bool CreateShader( void );

        virtual void Recompile( void );
    public:
        inline D3DVertexShader*& GetVertexShader_refPtrMutable( void ) 
        { return mVertexShader_ptr; }

        inline const D3DVertexShader* const GetVertexShader_ptrConst( void ) const
        { return mVertexShader_ptr; }

        inline D3DVertexShader* GetVertexShader_ptr( void ) const
        { return mVertexShader_ptr; }

    private:
        D3DVertexShader* mVertexShader_ptr;
    };
```

**//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

**Code - Source Files**

*Shader.cpp*

```
Shader::Shader( const std::string& filename, const std::string& shaderSrc, const std::string& entrypointFuncName,
                const std::string& shaderProfile, const RenderData_sptr& renderData_ptr,
                ShaderType sType ) :
                    Filename( filename ),
                    ShaderSrc( shaderSrc ),
                    EntrypointFuncName( entrypointFuncName ),
                    ShaderProfile( shaderProfile ),
                    mCompiledShader( NULL ),
                    mRenderData( renderData_ptr ),
                    ShdrType( sType ),
                    mIsCompiled( false )
        {   
        }

    bool Shader::CreateShader( void )
    {
        if( mIsCompiled )
            return false;

        mCompilerResultMessage = D3DX11CompileFromFileA(
            Filename.c_str(), 
            NULL, NULL,
            EntrypointFuncName.c_str(),
            ShaderProfile.c_str(),
            NULL, NULL, NULL,
            &mCompiledShader,
            NULL, NULL
        );

        return true;
    }

    void Shader::Recompile( void )
    {
        mIsCompiled = false;
        mCompiledShader->Release();
    }
```

**//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

--*VertexShader.cpp*--

```
VertexShader::VertexShader( const std::string& filename, const std::string& shaderSrc, const std::string& entrypointFuncName,
                                const std::string& shaderProfile, const RenderData_sptr& renderData_ptr )
                            :Shader( filename, entrypointFuncName, shaderSrc,
                                     shaderProfile, renderData_ptr, 
                                     ShaderType::ShaderTypeVertex ),
                             mVertexShader_ptr( NULL )
    {
    }

    bool VertexShader::CreateShader( void )
    {
        Shader::CreateShader();

        D3DDataBlob* errorBuffer = 0;
        D3DDataBlob* vertShaderBuffer = 0;

        const std::string errorPrefix = "Error Compiling Vertex Shader! - ";

        mRenderData->Device->CreateVertexShader(
            mCompiledShader->GetBufferPointer(),
            mCompiledShader->GetBufferSize(),
            NULL,
            &mVertexShader_ptr
        );

        HRESULT vertShaderCompileResult = 
            D3DX11CompileFromFileA( Filename.c_str(), 
                                    0, NULL,
                                    EntrypointFuncName.c_str(),
                                    ShaderProfile.c_str(),
                                    NULL, NULL,
                                    0, &vertShaderBuffer, &errorBuffer, 0 );

        if( FAILED( vertShaderCompileResult ) )
        {
            if( errorBuffer != 0 )
            {
                OutputDebugStringA( static_cast< char* >( errorBuffer->GetBufferPointer() ) );
                errorBuffer->Release();
            }

            std::cout << errorPrefix + "vertShaderCompileResult failed." << std::endl;

            return false;
        }

        if( errorBuffer != 0 )
            errorBuffer->Release();

        vertShaderCompileResult = mRenderData->Device->CreateVertexShader( 
            vertShaderBuffer->GetBufferPointer(),
            vertShaderBuffer->GetBufferSize(),
            0, &mVertexShader_ptr );


        if( FAILED( vertShaderCompileResult ) )
        {
            if( vertShaderBuffer )
                vertShaderBuffer->Release();

            std::cout << errorPrefix + "Device->CreateVertexShader( ... ) has failed" << std::endl;

            return false;
        }

        errorBuffer->Release();
        vertShaderBuffer->Release();
        delete errorBuffer;
        delete vertShaderBuffer;

        mIsCompiled = true;

        return true;
    }

    void VertexShader::Recompile( void )
    {
        Shader::Recompile();

        mVertexShader_ptr->Release();

        /*

        if( !this->CreateShader() )
        {
            //TODO throw error.
        }
        */
    }
```

**//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

--*PixelShader.cpp*--

```
PixelShader::PixelShader( 
                              const std::string& filename, 
                              const std::string& shaderSrc, 
                              const std::string& entrypointFuncName,
                              const std::string& shaderProfile, 
                              const RenderData_sptr& renderData_ptr 
                              )
                 : Shader( filename, shaderSrc, entrypointFuncName, shaderProfile, 
                           renderData_ptr, ShaderType::ShaderTypePixel ),
                   mPixelShader_ptr( NULL )
    {
    }

    bool PixelShader::CreateShader( void ) 
    {
        Shader::CreateShader();

        ID3D11InputLayout* inputLayout;

        D3DDataBlob* errorBuffer = 0;
        D3DDataBlob* pixShaderBuffer = 0;

        const std::string errorPrefix = "Error Compiling Pixel Shader! - ";

        mRenderData->Device->CreatePixelShader(
            mCompiledShader->GetBufferPointer(),
            mCompiledShader->GetBufferSize(),
            NULL,
            &mPixelShader_ptr
        );

        HRESULT pixShaderCompileResult = 
            D3DX11CompileFromFileA( Filename.c_str(), 
                                    0, NULL,
                                    EntrypointFuncName.c_str(),
                                    ShaderProfile.c_str(),
                                    NULL, NULL,
                                    0, &pixShaderBuffer, &errorBuffer, 0 );

        if( FAILED( pixShaderCompileResult ) )
        {
            if( errorBuffer != 0 )
            {
                OutputDebugStringA( static_cast< char* >( errorBuffer->GetBufferPointer() ) );
                errorBuffer->Release();
            }

            std::cout << errorPrefix + "pixelShaderCompileResult failed." << std::endl;

            return false;
        }

        if( errorBuffer != 0 )
            errorBuffer->Release();

        pixShaderCompileResult = mRenderData->Device->CreatePixelShader( 
            pixShaderBuffer->GetBufferPointer(),
            pixShaderBuffer->GetBufferSize(),
            0, &mPixelShader_ptr );


        if( FAILED( pixShaderCompileResult ) )
        {
            if( pixShaderBuffer )
                pixShaderBuffer->Release();

            std::cout << errorPrefix + "Device->CreatePixelShader( ... ) has failed" << std::endl;

            return false;
        }

        errorBuffer->Release();
        pixShaderBuffer->Release();
        delete errorBuffer;
        delete pixShaderBuffer;

        mIsCompiled = true;

        return true;
    }

    void PixelShader::Recompile( void )
    {
        Shader::Recompile();

        mPixelShader_ptr->Release();

        /*

        if( !this->CreateShader() )
        {
            //TODO throw error.
        }
        */
    }
```

**Update**

Since it seems like `FileUtility.obj` is what's throwing the errors, I decided to post them in hopes to figure something out here..

**FileUtility.hpp**

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include "Render/Shader.hpp"
#include "Render/PixelShader.hpp"
#include "Render/VertexShader.hpp" //<--these shader includes are inlcuded by .cpp as well

namespace stitch
{

    //--------------------------------------------------------------
    // NOTES:
    // - Omit file extension when specifying filename in FileUtility::LoadPixelShader/VertexShader functions - i.e., 
    //   use the identifier "TriangleVertexShader" as opposed to "TriangleVertexShader.hlsl"
    // - Omit file extension when using FileUtility::LoadTextFile.
    //--------------------------------------------------------------

    class FileUtility
    {
    public:
        //static std::string LoadTextFile( const std::string& filename );

        static VertexShader LoadVertexShader( const std::string& filename, const std::string& entrypointFuncName,
                                       const std::string& shaderProfile, const RenderData_sptr& renderData_ptr );

        static PixelShader  LoadPixelShader( const std::string& filename, const std::string& entrypointFuncName,
                                       const std::string& shaderProfile, const RenderData_sptr& renderData_ptr );

        static std::string Win32GetEnv( const char* name );
    };
}
```

**FileUtility.cpp**

```
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Static Constant Members
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    static const std::string& ShaderRoot     = FileUtility::Win32GetEnv( "STITCH_SRC" ) + std::string( "\\Resources\\Shaders\\" );
    static const std::string& ProjectRootDir = FileUtility::Win32GetEnv( "STITCH_SRC" );

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // 
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    const int MAX_CHAR_BUF = 65535; 

    static std::string _GetShaderSrc( const std::string& filename )
    {
        const std::string shaderFullpath = ShaderRoot + filename + ".fx";

        std::ifstream ifs    = std::ifstream( shaderFullpath.c_str(), std::ifstream::in );
        std::stringstream ss = std::stringstream( std::stringstream::in | std::stringstream::out );

        ss << ifs.rdbuf();

        ifs.close();

        return ss.str();
    }

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    std::string FileUtility::Win32GetEnv( const char* name )
    {
        static char buf[MAX_CHAR_BUF];

        if ( GetEnvironmentVariableA( name, buf, MAX_CHAR_BUF ) ){
            return std::string( buf );
        }
    }

    VertexShader FileUtility::LoadVertexShader( const std::string& filename, const std::string& entrypointFuncName,
                                         const std::string& shaderProfile, const RenderData_sptr& renderData_ptr )
    {
        const std::string shaderSrc = _GetShaderSrc( filename ); 

        VertexShader vs = VertexShader( filename, shaderSrc, entrypointFuncName, shaderProfile, renderData_ptr );

        return vs;
    }

    PixelShader FileUtility::LoadPixelShader( const std::string& filename, const std::string& entrypointFuncName,
                                         const std::string& shaderProfile, const RenderData_sptr& renderData_ptr )
    {
        const std::string shaderSrc = _GetShaderSrc( filename ); 

        PixelShader ps = PixelShader( filename, shaderSrc, entrypointFuncName, shaderProfile, renderData_ptr );

        return ps;
    }
```

Comment: the files where u get this error, if you replace `PixelShader` with `VertexShader` do u still get linking error?

Comment: you have a bug in `VertexShader` constructor. It's calling base class with inverted parameters. `entrypointFuncName` swapped with `shaderSrc` :)

Comment: I guess file generating `FileUtility.obj` is unable to locate `PixelShader` Nothing wrong with polymorphism.

Comment: @your first comment: yes, albeit not completely - I still have 4 errors, though that's an improvement. Second, thank you for spotting the bug. How would FileUtility not be able to locate PixelShader.hpp when it's included?

Comment: Note: I updated my question with the FileUtility class (at the bottom). Do you see anything peculiar?

Comment: `VertexShader vs = VertexShader` is local variable. It will be out of scope when returned by function. Either you have to implement copy constructor or you can create a pointer and pass the reference. e.g. `VertexShader* pVs = new VertexShader(); return pVs;` Note caller will have to release the memory.

Comment: Implemented copy constructors, but I'm still getting these errors. Wth??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14914/discussion-between-ankush-and-about-blank)